# Is there a report that will group by source of contact?

Tags: contacts, civireport

We have stared to use the contact source field to designate how our contacts get into CiviCRM. (event, membership, donation, helpline call etc.

I would like to be able to have a report that lets me filter by contact source and show the numbers from that source by month.  (A pivot tabe  would be OK but isn't ideal as contact source is a free text field.) I haven't be able to find a core report or reprot in an extension that will do either.

It seems like something other organisations might also be interested so someone might have already created an appropriate report.

Does anyone know of a report that will provides that summary information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal this could very easily be done with a View using Aggregation that would do this if you will accept that.

EDIT: The above should not have said 'very' easily ;-) but you can see / grab an example from Fuzion's [Treasure Trove](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/pivot-table-civi-data-example-month-created-v-source)